# Renault Master immobiliser stays off, engine turning over but not firing

Tags: ignition, renault, ignition-key, immobilizer

I have a 2003 Renault Master, which was left unused for about 4 months.

The little light on the dashboard (between STOP and SERV) does not even go on.

[image]

When I go to start it, the engine turns over but it does not stay on (as in the engine starts and then dies).

Also, I have charged the battery overnight and it is now fully charged.

When I first turn the key, all the lights on the dashboard go on, apart from the immobiliser red dot - which stays off. I am sure this should stay on until the engine is going...

Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is fuel.  Is it possible there is a problem with your fuel pump or fuel filter?

Comment: @jwh20 - I agree it is fuel related because a bit of easy-start will make it alive for just one split second (but then it will die again)... However, the immobiliser not working would show the same symptoms and since the immobiliser light is not behaving like it should, I think my best bet is to figure out what's going on there first...

Comment: I'm not clear why you suspect the immobilizer here.  Do you have any symptoms of that being an issue?

Comment: Symptoms are: no fuel reaching the engine and no immobiliser red light turning on, when key in position 2... It should go on and stay on til the engine is running for 5 seconds... I had the van for years. I am 100% sure that light should be on.